# Flash is not working after latest update

Tags: flash

Flash is not working, all I get is a black box.

I read lots of handy hints, found one that seems to be the answer I am looking for.

I went and got the adobe .tar.gz file as recommended. Went to put libflashplayer.so into /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/ but get told "permission denied" ??

What do I do please? how do I put the libflashplayer.so file into the lib?

Comment: Which version of ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't recommend to copy and to use downloaded files for flashplayer. Use the packages from the repositories instead.

Second, I personally like more the adobe propietary plugin, you can install it through your favourite package manager (sudo apt-get in the terminal or ubuntu software center as GUI, as an examples). search for adobe-flashplugin.
If you don't find result with such name probably you have to activate the non-free repositories, do it with the software and sources tool (use dash to search for it).
If you have already installed flashplugin-installer, probably it'll ask you if you want to replace it. press yes.

Other option is to reinstall flashplugin-installer, you can do it through the terminal typing: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer`

Comment: thank you, I would prefer not to install anything that has not come from the Software Center as i am not a computer expert. I really only use the official software centre and follow whatever update prompts come up.  Three times, since updating yesterday, the adobe flash plug in installer has popped up from the Software Center and said it has to go off to find some extra something then nothing happens for a while, then a box saying 'try again later' appears in the software update window.  Am i right in guessing i just have to wait till the Software Center gets some installer fix?

Comment: i attempted the 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer'  after typing in my pw, all i got was 'sudo: apt-get-: command not found'

Comment: @user276461 you must be mistyping. It is not sudo apt-get- but sudo apt-get

Comment: @user276461 say which version of ubuntu are you using, it's possible that it's out of support. In the meanwhile you can install and use google chrome (which has got built-in the last version of flash player). To do download it from here: https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/?platform=linux Select ubuntu 32 or 64 bits package as appropriate.

Comment: Hi.  I typed exactly what was written.  My os is Ubuntu 11.04,(ocelot oneric i think) my chrome browser's flash is not working either. All a bit weird as all i did was press update:(

Comment: @user276461 that version of ubuntu is out-of-support, that's why you can't update the flash package.
Upgrade to a more recent version or reinstall ubuntu, it's a good momment actually, since ubuntu 14.04 has just been released.

Comment: Thanks Akronix, I will look to do that then. I am a "if it ain't broke don't fix it" person so was perfectly happy rolling along with the older version, but now I know it is obviously broken, time to fix it!  Sincere gratitude from this fan of what Ubuntu is and does.  Even if, in the computer world anyway, i basically don't know how to 'change a lightbulb'  :)

Comment: Addendum:  I was actually 12.04 (forgot i had upgraded a while back)  Have now done two upgrades to 13.10 and things seem to be working again. should i upgrade further?  I am not bells n whistels guy, as long as i get to watch Breaking the Set on RT I am happy. Thanks for the helping hand.  Seems an obvious fix now :)  Been painting a lot lately so the old grey matter is a bit fried. Thanks again

Comment: @user276461 you're welcome. but, could you give me an arrow up or an accepted answer tick? It's good for me and for askubuntu :)

Comment: would love to, how do i do that?  I can't use the arrow vote thingys as I am new.  Where is the accepted answer tick ?  probably staring me in the face ... :)

Comment: check this @user276461 http://askubuntu.com/about
But I'm not sure if to have an ubuntu account is required :So